# Creating an array from a RBG array

Tags: python, dataframe, rgb

I have a raster in python [c, x, y] where C has three values using a combination of numbers from 0 to 255 such as ((0, 255, 0) that would represent the color green and the X and Y value are the row and column values of the raster. I need to create a python script with a color map that will assign a signal number to the C spot and replace the RBG value, for example if the color is red than the new C value becomes 1 if Blue than the c value becomes 3. However i need to account for slight variations in the RBG vaules such as (111, 143, 111) which is still green but for red and blue as well.

I have tried to create a range for each vaule bought it doesnt work for some reason. Any ideas?

```
def load_FOA_raster(patchfolder, string='FOA'):
    files = os.listdir(patchfolder) 
    tiffs =  [f for f in files if f.endswith('.JP2') and f.startswith(string)][0]
    FOA = gdal.Open(patchfolder+tiffs)

    raster = FOA.ReadAsArray()
    
    # Create a lookup table for the color values
    color_map = {
        (255, 0, 0): 1,  # Red
        ((140, 130, 130),(255, 0, 0)): 1,

        (0, 255, 0): 2,  # Green
        ((130, 140, 130),(0, 255, 0)): 2,

        (0, 0, 255): 3,  # Blue
        ((130, 130, 140),(0, 0, 255)): 3,

        (0,0,0): 4, #black
    }
    
    
    # Create the output filename
    foa_raster = np.zeros((1, raster.shape[1], raster.shape[2]))
    
    for i in range(raster.shape[1]):
        for j in range(raster.shape[2]):
            # Get the RGB values for the current pixel
            pixel_color = tuple(raster[:, i, j])

            # Check if the pixel color is in the color map
            if pixel_color in color_map:
                # If so, set the pixel value to the corresponding number
                foa_raster[0, i, j] = color_map[pixel_color]
            else:
                # If not, set the pixel value to 0 (or some other default value)
                foa_raster[0, i, j] = 0

    return foa_raster
```

My for loop is working. It works for black pixels and giving back a 4 in the correct spot but for the other colors it returns a 0 because of my else statment